# How to add app block to Shopify Customer Account page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to add an app block to Shopify Customer Account page.

I am able to add an app block to Home page and Product detail page, but unable to add it to Customer account page.

In Schema settings I have added Customer account template option
"templates": ["product", "index", "customers/account"]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot add app block to your theme is probably because the theme developer does not enable such behavior at the beginning. You need to do some changes to the source code in order to enable app block.

Solution:

1. In my case, the theme that I used does not allow me to add the app block.
   [I cannot add a section to include an app block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98kBT.png)
2. If the same situation applies to you, here is how I solve this problem.

Go to your Shopify admin, click on the themes to edit the code. Navigate to find the proper file to edit, you should be looking for 'account.liquid' or
'main-account.liquid'. The path should look something like this: templates > customers > account.liquid. (the name of the files and directory sometimes may vary).

3. Next, create a 'account.json' file under the same customers directory, copy&paste the following code into account.json:

```
     {
         "sections": {
            "main": {
              "type": "account",
              "settings": {
                "padding_top": 36,
                "padding_bottom": 36
              }
            }
          },
          "order": [
            "main"
          ]
        }
```

4. move the 'account.liquid' file into the "sections" directory.
   Add the following code into your account.liquid:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "t:sections.account.name",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "t:sections.all.padding.section_padding_heading"
      }, {
        "type": "range",
        "id": "padding_top",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100,
        "step": 4,
        "unit": "px",
        "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_top",
        "default": 36
      }, {
        "type": "range",
        "id": "padding_bottom",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100,
        "step": 4,
        "unit": "px",
        "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_bottom",
        "default": 36
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

**Note: You should be carefully checking if the value for "type" attribute in json file:**

```
"type": "account",
```

matches with the value for "name" attribute ("t:sections.**account**.name") in liquid file

```
"name": "t:sections.account.name",
```

e.g., if I changed the

```
"t:sections.account.name"
```

to

```
"t:sections.main-account.name"
```

This will raise an error. (you prob wondering what is "t:sections. .main doing here, good question, I don't know).

5. Go back to your shopify admin refresh the page to see if you can add the app block right now. If you succeeded, this is what you will get:

[a template section that enables you to add app block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zalck.png)

That is the end for the solution. Here is my personal explanation (not professional):

Shopify theme allows you to 'add section' in their online theme editor. Deep down in the code level, what it does is actually creating a json file to record any sections that you added in the editor. After adding an app (in my case, I created a custom app called 'pocky-du-card'), your account.json file will be looking something like this:

```
{
  "sections": {
    "main": {
      "type": "account",
      "settings": {
        "padding_top": 36,
        "padding_bottom": 36
      }
    },
    "1680234836ebfa6762": {
      "type": "apps",
      "blocks": {
        "1756c5a0-41fd-45c4-9f8f-1228909970ed": {
          "type": "shopify:\/\/apps\/pocky-du-card\/blocks\/card\/72688031-8cd1-4d7c-9f12-bf402f3cd04a",
          "settings": {
            "color": "#000000"
          }
        }
      },
      "block_order": [
        "1756c5a0-41fd-45c4-9f8f-1228909970ed"
      ],
      "settings": {
      }
    }
  },
  "order": [
    "main",
    "1680234836ebfa6762"
  ]
}
```

A new block of code with 'type' of 'app' is added.

The json file will trace back to an schema within a liquid file (that's the reason why you need to include a {%schema%} in your liquid file) under the 'section' folder to be validated ( that is why the 'type' attr in json has to match the 'name' attr in liquid).